# Printing out Path of second shortest path with Dijkstra. and second second path

Tags: c++

I am trying to find path of second shortest out of DIJKSTRA.Let's say I have the below vertices and their connection to each other. 
a:    c(19)    f(34)    i(58)    l(94)    o(108)    p(104)
b:    a(46)    d(47)    e(36)    j(82)    p(88)    q(91)    r(96)
c:    h(57)    j(49)    l(84)    m(106)
d:    j(44)    l(82)    r(80)
e:    d(22)    q(88)    r(79)    t(93)
f:    b(53)    d(19)    s(93)
g:    h(36)    j(102)    o(64)    p(65)
h:    a(60)    d(56)    f(46)    i(26)    l(47)    s(64)
i:    c(56)    d(48)    h(28)    p(50)
j:    c(51)    i(58)    m(108)
k:    c(68)    g(96)    i(51)    j(34)    l(55)    s(77)    t(77)
l:    b(76)    c(84)    e(69)    g(64)    j(73)    k(58)    q(25)    r(44)    t(36)
m:    f(93)    i(63)
n:    h(61)    i(64)    l(40)    p(28)    q(29)
o:    d(95)    e(84)    k(71)    q(16)
p:    b(85)    d(90)    g(67)    h(57)    j(84)    o(17)
q:    i(58)    n(28)    o(15)    s(11)    t(12)
r:    e(78)    j(57)    l(42)    n(72)    s(61)    t(63)
s:    c(104)    d(105)    e(90)    o(16)    q(10)
t:    a(119)    f(94)    i(64)    l(36)    m(31)    n(28)

And here is the code how I find the shortest path and second shortest path.

```
for (int count= 0; count < V-1; count++)
{
    int u = minDis(dist, sptSet);
    sptSet[u] = true;

    for (int v = 0; v < V; v++)
    {
        if (!sptSet[v] && graph[u][v] && dist[u] != INT_MAX && dist[u] + graph[u][v] < dist[v])
        {
            secDist[v] = dist[v];
            path[v] = u;
            dist[v] = dist[u] + graph[u][v];
            countVertices++;
        }
        else if(!sptSet[v] && graph[u][v] && dist[u] != INT_MAX &&        dist[u] + graph[u][v] < secDist[v])
        {
            secDist[v] = dist[u] + graph[u][v];
            secCountVertices++;
        }
    }
}
```

I got the correct distance and total number of nodes visited for second shortest path which is 130 length and Path (a l t) and I got the length of the second shortest path as well which is 131 but I have no idea how can I print out the second shortest path. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Please add some more relevatn code. Like the the definition and probably initialization of `secDist` and how you print it. The best would be a [Minimal reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also please add expected and actual output for a small example, instead of just stating that it is the wrong output.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-greedy-algo-7/) will point you in the right direction since the "printSolution()" seems to print out the path

Comment: I think that is the link for printing the shortest path which I already did. My goal is to print the second shortest path. Thanks